# AAC Bluetooth Audio on recent (21.10+) versions (Pulseaudio 15+)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

Previous to 21.10, I was using the additional pulseaudio-modules-bt to get AAC audio on my bluetooth headphones instead of SBC. This seems to be broken with 21.10, (I can build and install, but I don't end up with any PulseAudio AAC profiles). I've also tried building PulseAudio from master which doesn't give me the option for AAC either (even though AAC support has been merged to master).
Is there another piece of the puzzle I'm likely missing here?